# My ObservableObject Class Array Variable 'timeStep' Fails To Hold Values

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, observedobject

I have two ObservableObject classes: CarLotData and StopWatchManager. What I am trying to do is use my StopWatchManager class to load CarLotData property timeStep--which is a array Double type.

Here is my code for StopWatchManager:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class StopWatchManager: ObservableObject {
    
@ObservedObject var carLotData = CarLotData()

var timer = Timer()
    
@Published var mode: stopWatchMode = .stopped
@Published var secondsElapsed = 0.0
  
enum stopWatchMode {
case running
case stopped
case paused
}
    
func start() {

            
mode = .running
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { timer in
self.secondsElapsed = self.secondsElapsed + 0.1
}
        
}
func stop() {
        
          
timer.invalidate()
          
        
if carLotData.timeStep.count < 7 {
carLotData.timeStep.append(secondsElapsed)
print(carLotData.timeStep)
mode = .stopped
           
}
          
          
}
         
}
```

Here is my code for CarLotData:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class CarLotData: ObservableObject {


@Published var carLotData: Int = 0

@Published var carStep: [Double] = []




var id = UUID()
var newUsed: Int = 0
var powerType: Int = 0
var downPayment: Int = 0
var salesmanType: Int = 0
var appointment: Int = 0
var internet: Int = 0
var retail: Int = 0
var carType: Int = 0
var carBrand:  Int = 0
var purchaseType: Int = 0
var creditRank: Int = 0
var warranty: Int = 0
var service: Int = 0
var thirdParty: Int = 0
var timeStep: [Double] = []
var salesman: Int = 0   
}
```

Lastly here is my view where I get "timeStep = []" where I want an array of Double values.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CarLotDataView: View {

@ObservedObject var carLotData = CarLotData()
@ObservedObject var stopWachManager = StopWatchManager()

var body: some View {
    
    
List {

Group {


Text("Customer ID: \(carLotData.id)")
Text("Salesman: \(carLotData.salesman)")
Text("New/Used: \(carLotData.newUsed)")
Text("Power Type: \(carLotData.powerType)")
Text("Down Payment: \(carLotData.downPayment)")
Text("Salesman Type: \(carLotData.salesmanType)")
Text("Appointment: \(carLotData.appointment)")
}

Group {

Text("Internet: \(carLotData.internet)")
Text("Retail: \(carLotData.retail)")
Text("Car Type: \(carLotData.carType)")
Text("Car Brand: \(carLotData.carBrand)")
Text("Purchase Type: \(carLotData.purchaseType)")
Text("Credit Rankd: \(carLotData.creditRank)")
Text("Warranty: \(carLotData.warranty)")
Text("Service: \(carLotData.service)")
Text("Third Party: \(carLotData.thirdParty)")
Text("Time Steps: \(carLotData.timeStep)" as String)

}

}
    
}
}
```

Everything else works it's just that the values for my timer don't get transferred to my timeStep array. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access and update **CarLotData** from **StopWatchManager** and you are doing, but you are using completely another one in your View, You have to use the same one that you updated!

***The trick is always using the same reference you started!***

add this line to your **CarLotData**:

```
static let shared: CarLotData = CarLotData()
```

---

then use this code on **StopWatchManager**:

```
let carLotData = CarLotData.shared
```

***Do not use @ObservedObject inside Class, just use let, it will done the job.***

---

At last use this in your View:

```
@ObservedObject var carLotData = CarLotData.shared
```

For my personal app, I would use this down code:

```
@StateObject var carLotData = CarLotData.shared
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the `StopWatchManager` is an `ObservableObject`, not a `View`. So there's no point of using `@ObservedObject` there.

Comment: I do not wanted refactor the codes, just wanted make the code works as OP coded, thanks for that.

Comment: Worked exactly as intended. You mentioned using @StateObject var carLotData = CarLotData.shared "down code". Not clear on the reference and I haven't used StateObject at all. If you could expand on that a bit I would appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: As I said I would, but you can use which one you like, my reason is this, because that View would be the main interface with your app and model, I would like use StateObject instead ObservedObject, Apple says that in places that we can use StateObject it is better using than ObservedObject, ObservedObject controls and reads the source of data in crazy way, I would say much more than amount that StateObject does, therefore StateObject is better. Maybe there is some more other things, but I told you the important ones.

Comment: Thanks, your feedback has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating CarLotData twice. The right way would be to make sure you access the correct reference.

The other way is to make CarLotData a singleton. But that's only the right approach if you'll be using this data across many views.

```
class CarLotData: ObservableObject {
  static public let shared = CarLotData()
  private init() { }
}
```

Then you'd use it like so. Making sure to never call CarLotData()

```
Text("Internet: \(CarLotData.shared.internet)")
```